# Spring Security and LDAP MD5 authentication

Tags: spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I need to do spring security authentication where users whose passwords are stored in LDAP MD5 Hex encoding format using password comparison. For LDAP SHA encoding I can use `LDAPShaPasswordEncoder`. Which encoder should I use for LDAP MD5 encoding ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="passwordEncoder">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" />
            </property>
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>uid={0},ou=people</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <constructor-arg value="ou=groups" />
            <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(member={0})" />
            <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
            <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one that supports MD5. You'd have to implement `PasswordEncoder` yourself. You can use `LdapShaPasswordEncoder` as a guide. It should be pretty straightforward, especially without salt involved.

You should probably start looking at migrating to a more secure system which includes salt in the hashes. For example, perhaps your directory can support multiple formats and you can use SSHA for new users or password changes.